# datestr function in MATLAB to Java

Tags: java, matlab, date, datetime

I have a number format in a file that Matlab converts to a date string. The format is structured, for example, as **732161.8561226851**.

When I perform `datestr(732161.8561226851)` in Matlab, I get:

```
ans =

    '02-Aug-2004 20:32:49'
```

I wish to achieve the same output but as a Java function. I haven't seen this format before, however, and am unsure of the conversion process taken.

What is the process to convert this into a date string so I can create a Java function?

Comment: Appears to be a number of years. That number divided by 365.25 is about 2004.5499.

Comment: MATLAB's serial dates represent [the number of days from January 0, 0000](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Matlab epoch is January 0, 0000, so subtract 1 day from January 1:
    Instant matlabEpoch = Instant.parse("0000-01-01T00:00:00Z").minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

    Instant inst = matlabEpoch.plusMillis(
            Math.round(732161.8561226851 * TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
    System.out.println(inst);
```

This prints:

> 2004-08-02T20:32:49Z

I trust that [@Riley Jacob’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328869/5772882) is correct and see that it uses the long outdated `Date` class. So I wanted to give a modern version of the same answer. Other than avoiding the old-fashioned class it also has the advantage of leaving most of the calculation to library methods, which in turn gives clearer code.

I find it worth noting that we hit the same result as Matlab with millisecond precision. If the result had been one millisecond off, it would have been printed as either `2004-08-02T20:32:48.999Z` or `2004-08-02T20:32:49.001Z`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

The format is MATLAB's `DateNumber`: the number of days elasped since January 0, 0000. You can use Java's `toUTCString` with some modifying:

```
var d = new Date(dateMATLAB*86400000-62167305600000);
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

Where `dateMATLAB` is MATLAB's date output. The value `62167305600000` is the number of milliseconds which elapsed between year 0 and 1970. Using your example,

```
var d = new Date(732161.8561226851*86400000-62167305600000);
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

Will output

```
Mon, 02 Aug 2004 20:32:48 GMT
```